# Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 4 was incorrect on entry to DGETRF

Tags: intel-mkl

when I used MKL_LAPACK in Fortran，the error appended after runing my code.The forth parameter is IDA which represents the columns of the matrix.This is my code.Thanks for your help.

best wish！

```
program test
use lapack95

Implicit None
Integer :: i,j,k
real*8 :: w_boundary(8)   !以为梁在二维方向上的边界条件
real*8,dimension(8,8) :: Q    
real*8 :: longth_e  !单元长度
real*8 :: A(8)
!---------------------------------------------
!LApack中的参数

integer :: ipiv(8)
integer ::lda
integer ::lwork, info
real*8, allocatable ::  work(:)

!---------------------------------------------
longth_e=2.0d0
lda =size(Q(:,1))
lwork=8*8
ipiv=0.0d0
Q = reshape ((/1.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0, &
               0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,1.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0, &
               0.0d0,1.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0, &
               0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,1.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0, &
               1.0d0,longth_e,longth_e**2.0d0,longth_e**3.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,&
                            0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,1.0d0,longth_e,2.0d0*longth_e**2.0d0,3.0d0*longth_e**3.0d0,&
                            0.0d0,1.0d0,2.0d0*longth_e,3.0d0*longth_e**2.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,&
                            0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,1.0d0,2.0d0*longth_e,3.0d0*longth_e**2.0d0/),(/8,8/))

Q=transpose(Q)
allocate(work(lwork))
call dgetrf(8, 8, Q,lda, ipiv, info)
 if (info==0) then
   write(*,*) "Inverse Matrix:"
   write(*,'(3f10.5)') Q
 else 
     write(*,*) "LU is error,please check subroutine MATRIX_A"
 end if
call dgetri(8, Q, lda, ipiv, work, lwork, info)
 if (info==0) then
   write(*,*) "Inverse Matrix:"
   write(*,'(3f10.5)') Q
 else 
     write(*,*) "inverse_Q is error,please check subroutine MATRIX_A"
 end if
 

deallocate(work)
!A=matmul(Q,w_boundary)  !求A
End program
```

help me solve this program

Comment: From the code provided by you, it seems the subroutines are missing. Could you please cross-verify the input parameters?
Also, please find the examples in the path **C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2023.1.0\examples\examples_core_f.zip\f\lapack\source**  
For more reference please see this [link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-0/getrf.html)